# Calling local Julia package from C

Tags: c, julia

The Julia documentation shows examples of how to call Base Julia functions from C (e.g. `sqrt`), which I've been successful in replicating. What I'm really interested in doing is calling locally developed Julia modules and it's not at all clear from the documentation how one would call non-Base functions. There are some discussion threads on the issue from a few years ago, but the APIs appear to have changed in the meantime. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Julia, but could the section [_Creating C-Compatible Julia Function Pointers_](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#Creating-C-Compatible-Julia-Function-Pointers-1) help? You might have to kick things off from Julia so you can pass the results of one or more `@cfunction` calls into C so that your C code can then call the Julia functions at a later date.

Comment: @TripeHound Unfortunately my use-case involves building up and tearing down Julia from within C.

Comment: Have you checked if the following instructions https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/embedding/ work for you? In particular have you tried to pass a string to `jl_eval_string` function that first loads a non-Base module and then executes what you need to execute, or even - at the extreme passing `include("path_to_Julia_script_that does_all_the_required_work")`?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Yes, I tried all that before posting my question. `jl_eval_string` returns a NULL pointer.

Comment: Can you please post what is your code exactly.

Comment: I'm not at work right now, so it will have to wait until tomorrow. I'll incorporate the code into the question body. In the meantime, if you have a working example, please feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why `jl_eval_string("using SomeModule")` returns `NULL` is simply because `using SomeModule` returns `nothing`.

You can use functions from other modules by first importing the module, and then retrieving function objects from that Julia module into C. For example, let's use the package [`GR`](https://github.com/jheinen/GR.jl) and its `plot` function. We can get the `plot` function with

```
jl_eval_string("using GR") // this returns nothing
jl_module_t* GR = (jl_module_t *)jl_eval_string("GR") // this returns the module

/* get `plot` function */
jl_function_t *plot = jl_get_function(GR, "plot");
```

Here we passed `GR` module as the first argument to `jl_get_function`. We can, knowing the fact that things will be loaded into the module `Main` and `plot` is exported from `GR`, use the following snippet instead to do the same. Note that `jl_main_module` holds a pointer to the module `Main`.

```
jl_eval_string("using GR")

/* get `plot` function */
jl_function_t *plot = jl_get_function(jl_main_module, "plot");
```

We can also use `plot`s qualified name.

```
/* get `plot` function */
jl_function_t *plot = jl_get_function(jl_main_module, "GR.plot");
```

That said, here is the complete example plotting an array of values using `GR`. The example uses the first style to get the function `GR.plot`.

```c
#include <julia.h>

JULIA_DEFINE_FAST_TLS() // only define this once, in an executable (not in a shared library) if you want fast code.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* required: setup the Julia context */
    jl_init();

    /* create a 1D array of length 100 */
    double length = 100;
    double *existingArray = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*length);

    /* create a *thin wrapper* around our C array */
    jl_value_t* array_type = jl_apply_array_type((jl_value_t*)jl_float64_type, 1);
    jl_array_t *x = jl_ptr_to_array_1d(array_type, existingArray, length, 0);

    /* fill in values */
    double *xData = (double*)jl_array_data(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        xData[i] = i * i;

    /* import `Plots` into `Main` module with `using`*/
    jl_eval_string("using GR");
    jl_module_t* GR = (jl_module_t *)jl_eval_string("GR");;

    /* get `plot` function */
    jl_function_t *plot = jl_get_function(GR, "plot");

    /* create the plot */
    jl_value_t* p = jl_call1(plot, (jl_value_t*)x);


    /* display the plot */
    jl_function_t *disp = jl_get_function(jl_base_module, "display");
    jl_call1(disp, p);

    getchar();

    /* exit */
    jl_atexit_hook(0);
    return 0;
}
```

### Including a Julia module from a local file and use it in C

I do not know what is exactly meant by a local Julia package, but, you can  `include` your files and then import the modules in those files to do the same. Here is an example module.

```
# Hello.jl
module Hello
export foo!

foo!(x) = (x .*= 2) # multiply entries of x by 2 inplace

end
```

To include this file you need to use `jl_eval_string("Base.include(Main, \"Hello.jl\")");`. For some reason, embedded Julia cannot access `include` directly. You need to use `Base.include(Main, "/path/to/file")` instead.

```
jl_eval_string("Base.include(Main, \"Hello.jl\")");
jl_eval_string("using Main.Hello"); // or just '.Hello'
jl_module_t* Hello = (jl_module_t *)jl_eval_string("Main.Hello"); // or just .Hello
```

Here is the complete example in C.

```
#include <julia.h>

JULIA_DEFINE_FAST_TLS() // only define this once, in an executable (not in a shared library) if you want fast code.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* required: setup the Julia context */
    jl_init();

    /* create a 1D array of length 100 */
    double length = 100;
    double *existingArray = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*length);

    /* create a *thin wrapper* around our C array */
    jl_value_t* array_type = jl_apply_array_type((jl_value_t*)jl_float64_type, 1);
    jl_array_t *x = jl_ptr_to_array_1d(array_type, existingArray, length, 0);
    JL_GC_PUSH1(&x);
    /* fill in values */
    double *xData = (double*)jl_array_data(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        xData[i] = i * i;

    /* import `Hello` module from file Hello.jl */
    jl_eval_string("Base.include(Main, \"Hello.jl\")");
    jl_eval_string("using Main.Hello");
    jl_module_t* Hello = (jl_module_t *)jl_eval_string("Main.Hello");

    /* get `foo!` function */
    jl_function_t *foo = jl_get_function(Hello, "foo!");

    /* call the function */
    jl_call1(foo, (jl_value_t*)x);

    /* print new values of x */
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%.1f ", xData[i]);

    printf("\n");
    JL_GC_POP();

    getchar();

    /* exit */
    jl_atexit_hook(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long to award the bounty - I figured accepting the answer would automatically award it.